# Footer width sets too much

Tags: html, css

When i make position:absolute, width:100% footer sets too much width for my screen, here is my code:

```
<p class="footer" style="font-weight:bold;color:#D9D9D9;border: 15px solid #272727;letter-spacing:1pt;word-spacing:2pt;font-size:10px;text-align:center;font-family:courier new, courier, monospace;line-height:0;"> Text    </p>
```

css:

```
    .footer{     
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    text-align: center;    
    bottom: 0px; 
    }
```

and i want to make him stay on page bottom even if nothing writed in because in other pages footers goes in middle of the screen

Comment: try not using position absolute

Comment: @ShaigKhaligli OP wants the footer stay on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/vrd4nfL4/3/

Try with `overflow:hidden`

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: try overflow-x:hidden

Comment: worked, but other problem that in some pages footer goes not in the bottom

Comment: for sticky footer, use " bottom: 0; " in footer style